# Vue - display/create component from a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

One thing that I have been struggling to figure out how to do better is modals. Currently, I am registering the modal component on each Vue that needs it. However, this feels rather sloppy, as I am having to register the component several times. Even using mix-ins just does not feel like an elegant solution. What would be optimal to be able to do is to mimic JavaScript's `alert()` method on the Vue instance. For example, be able to call `this.ShowModal(Header, Body)`

However, from my understanding, there is no way to accomplish this

Take for example my Modal example. You could have a modal template like this:

```HTML
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
    <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

            <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
                default header
            </slot>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            <slot>
            </slot>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
                default footer
                <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
                </button>
            </slot>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </transition>
</script>
```

Then you would have to reference the component over and over again like this

```HTML
<template>
    <button @click="displayModal">Display the Modal Alert</button>
    
    <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">    
      <h3 slot="header"> This is a good header </h3>
      <p>
           Look at me I am the body! You have seen me {{displayCount}} times!
      </p>
    </modal>
</template>
<script>
   components: {modal},
   data: {
       showModal: false,
       displayCount: 0
   },
   methods: {
      displayModal(){
        this.displayCount++
        this.showModal = true;
      }
   }
</script>
```

If you wanted to reuse the component for several messages from within the parent you would then have to add several more variables to store things such as the header and body. You could put some of the logic into a mixin but you would still have to have the clutter of adding the modal component and possibly the mixin.

This brings us to the question. Is there a way to create a function in the Vue instance that would allow for us to dynamically create a Modal component and fill in the slots with arguments passed to the function? e.g. `this.ShowModal("This is a good header", "Look at me I am the body!")`

Comment: Can you clarify your concern with the component reuse -- specifically "adding more variables to handle things such as the header and body"? Why would you need to add variables for that when it's already given by the slot in the template?

Comment: @tony19 My apologizes. I have edited the question to make that clearer. I mean for reusing it within the parent component. Let's say that I want to use it for 8 different messages. I would either have to create 8 show variables, or a `show, header, and body` variable to output the data in the desired format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Vue.extend()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) create a "modal" constructor and create a instance,you can mount it to DOM dynamically by $mount or other ways

In Modal example:

modal.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        {{message}} //your modal content
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        name: 'modal',
        data(){
            return {
                message: '',  
            }
        },
        methods:{
            /************/
            close () {
                /****this.$destroy()****/
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

modal.js:

```js
import myModal from 'modal.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
const modalConstructor = Vue.extend(myModal)

const modal = (options,DOM)=>{
    const modalInstance =  new modalConstructor({data:options})
    modalInstance.vm = modalInstance.$mount() //get vm
    const dom = DOM || document.body   // default DOM is body
    dom.appendChild(modalInstance.vm.$el)  // mount to DOM
    return modalInstance.vm
}

export default modal
```

now you can create a Modal component by a function like this:

```js
import showModal from 'modal.js'
showModal({message:"..."})
```